# Challenges with specifying different lags in a vecm in r

Tags: r, time-series

I am constructing a vecm after running a Johansen test of cointegration. I ran the AIC lag selection criterion per variable and discovered that each variable (column) has a different lag order. I am trying to construct the vecm with these different lag orders per column

I used the following code:

```
vecm_custom <- VECM(data, lag = c(9, 9, 3, 5, 8), r = 1, estim = "2OLS")

# The component - lag =c(9,9,3,5,8).., represents the various lags as derived from the AIC criterion

I get the error message - "condition is > 1"
```